# Using # in a path name for a hyperlink in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, path

I am creating a vba For loop to cycle through cells in a range and creating a hyperlink to file folders based on the text within the cell. See below:

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100")

For Each cell In rng

    address1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\Comm Review\Item #" & 
    cell.Text

    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:=address1, TextToDisplay:=cell.Text
    End If
Next cell
```

The cell value will be something like 1001.T0502 and the actual folder name that I am linking to will be Item #1001.T0502. So in my address1 variable i create the path to the folder.

However, when I do this it creates the path with everything but #1001.T0502 and ends up stopping at "\Item". If I were to drop the number sign(#) though it includes the number and ends up being Item 1001.T0502. For some reason the number sign stops it from making the correct path. What am I missing here? There are already 200 folders with the number sign in the folder name so going back now and taking it out would be too much work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I ran your code on a single cell, which contained `1407.T0502`.  The hyperlink created was:  `C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\Comm Review\Item#1407.T0502`  Note that the space was removed, but the number was still there.

Comment: Yeah, I think I tried testing that before too and it worked, but all the folders are unfortunately named "Item #..." with a space between item and #. I'm assuming vba has a problem with the number sign by itself, but it shouldn't as its within a string. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: To be able to include the space, try surrounding the link address with double quotes.  But I cannot check it this evening.  (something like `address1 = """C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\Comm Review\Item #" & cell.Text & """"`

Comment: No worries. Just tried that, and still no luck unfortunately. I even tried `"C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\Comm Review\Item" & " " & "#" & cell.Text' and once again it just stops before the number sign.

Comment: On a side note, renaming folders wouldn't really be much work. Just write a quick script to go remove those hash symbols. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198701.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198721.aspx.

Comment: On further testing, it seems that although I can create a hyperlink string that includes the `#`, clicking on the hyperlink does not work `Cannot open the specified file`, so I guess this doesn't work in 2016 either.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a pound character in a file name for a hyperlink in an Office program. See official Microsoft documentation here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/202261/you-cannot-use-a-pound-character-in-a-file-name-for-a-hyperlink-in-an

Seems totally wacko if you ask me, but alas, I think you're trying to solve an unsolvable problem.

But, fear not, I did think of a potential work around. Instead of making the cells actual hyperlinks, you could just recolor the cell to blue with an underline and then use this little trick to capture when the cell is selected and open Windows Explorer to the corresponding file path.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
            Shell "explorer ""C:\Users\Desktop\Tests\Comm Review\Item #" & Target.Value & """", vbNormalFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The only downside I can see here is that selecting the cell with the arrow keys also opens the corresponding folder. There may be a work around to that, but I don't have time at the moment to research it.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I wish I knew that before we created all the folders haha. Oh well. It appears yours looks like it would suffice as a work around. I'll have to test it out more tomorrow morning. I just worry about the long term reliability of that solution with multiple people using the spreadsheet compared to having an actual "clickable" hyperlink. Thanks for your help everybody!

Comment: Honestly, if I were you, I'd write a quick script to remove the hash symbols from your file names and move on. I've done similar tasks before, renaming thousands of folders, and it didn't take long.

Comment: Here's another link regarding renaming folders: https://superuser.com/questions/197380/how-do-i-find-and-replace-a-character-in-filenames-in-windows-7-using-explorer

Comment: FWIW - I assume the reason that a `#` can't be used is because that is the way that links jump to somewhere part-way through a webpage, i.e. a "bookmark".

Comment: @YowE3K, you may be right, but you'd think they would have incorporated that behavior when you open a URL.

Comment: @gluc7, did you get things sorted out?

Comment: maybe because the pound character is a date "specifier" (is that the right word?) .... `debug.print #12-23-56#`

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't able to get back quicker. We were able to remove the hash symbols through a script one of my co-workers had written just as you said earlier. After that the hyperlinks worked fine. Thanks again!